# Allure. Unsatisfied dependency of type [interface com.atlassian.struts.TextProvider]

Tags: bamboo, allure

We have CI Bamboo and allure plugin for it.
So, if I set allure version as 1.3.9 - all is Ok, but if version is 1.4.0+, I get error on report's publishing stage (maven step ends successfully):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.atlassian.struts.TextProvider] is defined: Unsatisfied dependency of type [interface com.atlassian.struts.TextProvider]: expected at least 1 matching bean
```

This problem starts after webDriverFactory version increasing or after moving remote agents to a new VM

Answer (score 0):

Allure Bamboo Plugin is not supported well. You can generate report using Allure CLI just as usual build step. And then publish it as regular HTML report.